# Validation Rule for Start Date should be less than the End Date

Tags: validation-rule

Two Fields, Start Date, End Date -The validation rule for start date should be less than the end date.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) then [edit] your question to explain what you have tried and where you are stuck. As it stands this could be closed without answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the solution below.

```
Start_Date__c > CloseDate
```

I could see that you are new to this forum here so I suggest you please read the guidelines and post what you have tried as a solution.

Comment: This sort of simplistic validation rule is, IMHO, something of an anti-pattern. The best practice is to ensure the validation only applies when the record `ISNEW` or where one or other of the fields being compared `ISCHANGED`. Taking this simple approach may prevent other changes where these fields have not changed.

Comment: And even if using this simple VR - I would also change it to >=, since in this case, start_date can equal closedate, which does not fit OP request

Comment: Start_Date__c > CloseDate it is working